# LinkedIn Share API (missing r_member_social permission)

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the Share API in Linkedin in order to retrieve posts from an user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner

I get the following error making the call:
Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/authors]
status:403

From all my digging I saw that probably I need r_member_social permission, but there is no way I can see how I can get that for my application.

Can anyone guide me how I can get that for my application so I can retrieve one's shares with some statistics.

Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Comment: Did you get this sorted?